# Change DateFormat or Default Locale in Struts2 webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, internationalization

I have been having problem with my DateFormat. en_US, en_UK, en_IN are all same for my webapp. The only thing that matters is dateformat to be used throughout the webapp.

First i tried to override the dateformat of en locale, apparently i failed to find any good solution on how to do that.

Hence i planned to change the default locale to en_IN, because we use the date format as dd/mm/yy

No effect, then en_GB... but no luck.

Please note that i did restart tomcat after making changes but no luck.

my `dispatcher-servlet.xml` in WEB-INF sets it as follows.

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
             <property name="paramName" value="request_locale" />
    </bean>
<!--    <mvc:interceptors>
  <mvc:interceptor>
     <mvc:mapping path="/locale*"/>
         <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" >
         <property name="paramName" value="request_locale" />
     </bean>
</mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
-->
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
 <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
<bean id="mappingHandler" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
<property name="interceptors">
   <list>
    <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
   </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
    <constant name="struts.locale" value="en_GB" />
```

to struts.xml did the job.

If there are any possible side-effects, please let me know

Comment: Been using it as such till now.. no problem faced.. hence i mark this the answer